# Extender lags on devices discovery

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I hope the title wasn't really off-target, it's quite hard to clearly explain this issue since I don't know technical terms.

The issue though is pretty simple. When I switch from my router's wireless network to my extender's wireless network there's a lag of some minutes in the device discovery.

I'll give a practical example:

> Sonos is connected to network A.
>
> I'm connected to network A as well and iPhone can find Sonos.
>
> I switch to extender's network B and iPhone can't find Sonos anymore.
>
> A minute later or so iPhone refreshes the list of connected devices on network B and finds Sonos again.

Now, those devices are only for example purpose, it happens with any kind of device.

I'm sure I could live with this lag, but I'm wondering what's the cause behind it and if there's a way to remove it. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

*Context: All devices are on same subnet, extender is a mirror of router settings (gateway, DNS, etc)*

*DHCP is ON, UPnP is OFF on the router*